# What update commands should I use on Mint 19.3?

Tags: debian, linux-mint, apt

historically, to update my system, I used

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
snap refresh
```

but I see that now the newer `apt` command is recommended in Debian-based distros instead of `apt-get`, and the equivalent should be

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

However, it looks like Mint has (or had?) by default its own `apt` command that's a Python script wrapping the old commands in a different way from the new `apt`.

My questions are:

- Does Linux Mint, in its 19.3 version, still have that custom `apt` command, or has it replaced it with the standard Debian one?
- If so, what is the recommended way of dealing with it? What commands on it are equivalent to `apt update`, `apt full-upgrade`? How are its commands different from the newer `apt` in Debian-based distros?